# evasive20:error when installing joomla 3.3

Tags: php, apache, joomla

I am getting evasive20:error when installing joomla on my server. The server is running ubuntu 14.04.

The error comes when the database installation starts. The first two configuration screens goes fine (general info and database parameters). Then when reaching the third and final screen the install will hang forever. The only error I can find is in the apache2 error.log.

Any ideas how to prevent this hang?

```
[Mon Jun 09 09:04:26.585041 2014] [evasive20:error] [pid 2712] [client xx.xx.233.44:64657]
client denied by server configuration: /var/www/joomla/installation/index.php, referer: 
http://xx.xx.xx/installation/index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The mod_evasive seems to think that joomla does something funky or creates a loop of some kind.

for Ubuntu

```
a2dismod evasive

run install and 

a2enmod evasive

again
```